# How to write package-statements for nested packages?

Tags: java, java-package

If I have a class in a sub-package like `sub-package-name`, which is in a parent-package like `higher-level-package-name`, do I just write

```
package "sub-package-name";
```

Or also add the parent-package, maybe like

```
package "sub-package-name";
package "higher-level-package-name";
```

Comment: You need the full package name in a package declaration, so `package highest-level-package-name.sub-package-name;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Example

You are only supposed to write a **single** `package` statement, with the **full name** of the package. So if you have a directory hierarchy for your packages like:

```java
foo/
└─ bar/
   └─ baz/
      └─ Test.java
```

Your `Test.java` file would have a statement like:

```java
package foo.bar.baz;
```

### Nested packages

Java itself actually has **no concept of nested packages**.

As far as the language is concerned,

- `foo`,
- `foo.bar` and
- `foo.bar.baz`

are considered three **independent packages**. *Sub-packages* or *parent-packages* are not a thing to Java.

Consequently, *package-visibility* also does **not carry over** to *sub-* or *parent-packages*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! But what does this statement means, "Consequently, package-visibility also does not carry over to sub- or parent-packages."?

Comment: When you use package-visibility (the fourth visibility next to `public`, `protected` and `private`), it will only apply to the current package and not to sub- or parent-packages. So a package-visible field in a parent-package will not be visible to a class in a sub-package or vice versa.

Comment: I have sometimes seen this statement: `package test.pkg`. Why `.pkg`, why not simply package name?

Comment: i havent seen that yet - but u are free to name ur packages whatever u want.